# Optaplanner, using experimental collector issue

Tags: optaplanner

I tried the experimental collector and have some issues with it. I need to find the breaks between sequences, it does find the sequences - it seems, so I would expect it to also recognize the breaks, but i get none. I would expect to be able to call .getNextBreak() and then .getNext Sequence(), since there are returned several sequences, but there are no breaks so I cannot jump back and forth and figure it out that way either.
Maybee it has to do with the join only joins in the the used timegrains.

In a timegrainfact list of 0-9 I assigned 3 meetings, It does find the sequences it seems, but I dont get any of breaks that Im looking for. I would expect two sequences only as the two of them overlap, being (0-1 and 4-7) and breaks from (2-3 and 8-9).

```
ConstraintCollectors.consecutive:
Meetingassign ID: 6   Sequence [7, 5, 6], breakList=[]
Meetingassign ID: 5   Sequence [5, 6, 4], breakList=[]
Meetingassign ID: 4   Sequence [0,1], breakList=[]
ConstraintCollectors.breaks:
<empty>

protected Constraint unusedTimeGrains(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(TimeGrain.class)        
            .join(MeetingAssignment.class, 
                    Joiners.overlapping((TimeGrain timegrain)-> timegrain.getGrainIndex(), 
                            (TimeGrain timegrain)-> timegrain.getGrainIndex()+1, 
                            (MeetingAssignment assignment) ->assignment.getStartingTimeGrain().getGrainIndex(),
                            (MeetingAssignment assignment) ->assignment.getStartingTimeGrain().getGrainIndex() + assignment.getDurationInGrains()
                            )
                    )                
                    .groupBy((timegrain, assingment) ->   
                    timegrain, 
                             (timegrain, assingment) ->   assingment,
                              ConstraintCollectors.consecutive((timegrain, assingment) ->  
                              timegrain, 
                                      TimeGrain::getGrainIndex
                                      )
                              )
                    .flattenLast(ConsecutiveInfo::getConsecutiveSequences)
                    .penalizeConfigurable( (timegrain, assingment,shiftSequence) -> shiftSequence.getLength()) // not-e here is rewarded not penalized, as its overlaps not gaps that is found  
            .asConstraint(MeetingConstraintConfiguration.UNUSED_TIME_GRAIN);
}
```

It turned out that the problem was that TimeGrain did not implement a suitable equals, hence an internal map was just overwritten and any item appeared as the next in line.

Comment: Have you tired using `ConsecutiveInfo::getBreaks` which directly returns the `IntervalBreak` (versus using `ConsecutiveInfo::getConsecutiveSequences` which returns consecutive sequences)?